# Creating a second applet(window) in processing

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe, processing

Hello guys i am trying to do a code where i can create a second applet in processing by passing on a sensible area.

the code works fine except for 1 thing.

when it passes over the sensible area it creates in a loop the same frame.

here is the code.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

PFrame f;
secondApplet s;

void setup() {
  size(600, 340);

}

void draw() {
  background(255, 0, 0);
  fill(255);
}     

void mousePressed(){

  PFrame f = new PFrame();
}


public class secondApplet extends PApplet {

  public void setup() {
    size(600, 900);
     noLoop();
  }
  public void draw() {
    fill(0);
    ellipse(400, 60, 20, 20);
  }
}

public class PFrame extends JFrame {
  public PFrame() {

    setBounds(0, 0, 600, 340);
    s = new secondApplet();
    add(s);
    s.init();
    println("birh");
    show();
  }
}
```

This code creates the second applet by just clicking in any region of the frame, but if you keep clicking it will create more frames of the same applet.

what i want is that once i click it creates only 1 frame and no more.

can you help me please?
thanks ;)

Comment: Avoid using Swing with Processing. Use Processing specific GUI libraries. Read this page: http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html They specifically discourage use of AWT and Swing with Processing. There are plenty of Processing specific GUI libraries, one example is ControlP5 which I personally like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted won't compile, as you have no top-level encapsulating class declared, so I'm curious about why you say it works.

Regarding your issue, you have the field `PFrame f` declared at the top, but in `mousePressed()` you declare another one. This variable `f` is different from the first variable. To solve your problem, you probably want your code to look something like:

```
void mousePressed() {
  if (f == null) {
    f = new PFrame();
  }
}
```

This will allow you to create the new frame, but only once. I recommend you choose more descriptive variable names, though. Also, it should be `SecondApplet`, not `secondApplet`.

Comment: i am calling the classes here
PFrame f;
secondApplet s;



it worked ty so much.

Comment: No, you're declaring the those variables there. Nothing is being instantiated. Again, though, this is valid Java code, as there is no encapsulating class those variables to. Also, the variable `f` you declare in `mousePressed()` is different from the first one you declared, even though they have the same name, because they have different scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

PFrame f = null;
secondApplet s;

void setup() {
  size(600, 340);

}

void draw() {
  background(255, 0, 0);
  fill(255);
}     

void mousePressed(){

  if(f==null)f = new PFrame();
}


public class secondApplet extends PApplet {

  public void setup() {
    size(600, 900);
     noLoop();
  }
  public void draw() {
    fill(0);
    ellipse(400, 60, 20, 20);
  }
  /*
   * TODO: something like on Close set f to null, this is important if you need to 
   * open more secondapplet when click on button, and none secondapplet is open.
   */
}

public class PFrame extends JFrame {
  public PFrame() {

    setBounds(0, 0, 600, 340);
    s = new secondApplet();
    add(s);
    s.init();
    println("birh");
    show();
  }
}
```